# How can I count number of items in a list based on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list `List<TestObj> testList`

```
class TestObj
{
    public int type;
    public string phase; 
}

1 Phase1
1 Phase1
2 Phase1
2 Phase2
```

I want to get count of specific type and phase.  So I tried this

```
 var count = testList.Count(x=> x.type == 1 && x.phase.Equals("Phase1"));
```

I got zero.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: This won't compile as is, (because of what @Jeroen said) and without seeing any data it's pretty difficult to guess why you didn't get any results. Please post your *actual* code and a short sample of the data you're dealing with.

Comment: there is **no way** to get 0 from that code,show us how did you initialize and populate your list and provide your actual code for next time!

Comment: Your added sample data returns one not zero as result: `var testList = new List<TestObj>(){ new TestObj { type = 1, phase = "Phase1" }, new TestObj { type = 2, phase = "Phase1" }, new TestObj { type = 2, phase = "Phase2" }};`

Answer (score 5):

Use `==` for comparisons in C#. The [`= operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) is for assignments only.

```
var count = testList.Count(x=> x.type == 1 && x.phase == "Phase1");
```

[== Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)

> I got zero.

Your code would not even comile.

Maybe you are using `==` instead and you have an item with  `phase="phase1"`. C# is case-sensitive, you can use `String.Equals` with `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` :

```
var count = testList.Count(x=> x.type == 1 && "Phase1".Equals(x.phase, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```